# Getting info and field name from database and align them together in console application

Tags: c#, sql-server

Basically, I am getting information from a database which I've managed to do. Now I need to get the column name to display in the console application. I'm also trying to align them like they would show in sql server 2012.  For now I've tried to get the column name but it doesn't want to work and I am stuck.  any help is appreciated.  below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace sql_connection
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {                             
        string conn = null;
        SqlConnection connection;
        conn= ("Data Source=database\\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=jobs;User ID=user;Password=passs");

        connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        try{

            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_Date,[jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_FromTime,[jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_ToTime, [jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_User,[jobs].[dbo].[table login].login_Email FROM [jobs].[dbo].[table hours]INNER JOIN [jobs].[dbo].[table login] ON [jobs].[dbo].[table hours].whd_User = [jobs].[dbo].[table login].login_LoginId WHERE  DATEDIFF(DAY,[whd_Date],GETDATE())<=7 AND   (whd_ToTime = '' OR whd_ToTime IS NULL) AND(whd_User=login_LoginId)");
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var columns = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
            }

            var list = new List<string>();

            while(reader.Read())
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
                }
                  var s = string.Format("{4},{3},{2}, {1}, {0}",
                   reader["whd_ToTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader["whd_ToTime"].ToString(), 
                   reader["whd_FromTime"] == DBNull.Value? "NULL" : reader  ["whd_FromTime"].ToString(), 
                   reader["whd_Date"].ToString(), 
                   reader["whd_User"].ToString(),
                   reader["login_Email"].ToString());
                  Console.WriteLine(i);
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                list.Add(s);




            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var s in list)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(s);
            }



            connection.Close();

             MailAddress to = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");


            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);


            mail.Subject = ("missed punch clock");

            mail.Body = sb.ToString();

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                "email@gmail.com", "passworrd");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Sending email..");
            smtp.Send(mail);
        } 




        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }                       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _not working_? You get any exception or error message? Did you debug your code and see your values?

Comment: instead of the column names it gives me "Systems.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]"

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: in the command prompt it shows first that line then the info under it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Systems.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]` is what you get from using the `.ToString()` method on a `List<string>`, so I'm guessing that the line `Console.WriteLine(i);` is actually `Console.WriteLine(list);`.
If I'm correct, then you should replace it with `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());`

To properly align your output you can use tabs (`"\t"`) instead of spaces between the strings:

```
var s = string.Format("{4}\t, {3}\t, {2}\t, {1}\t, {0}";

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t,", list.ToArray()).TrimEnd(","));
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: okay so this worked my fault, now how can I align them like they would be in a database?

Comment: You might want to use more then one tab between the columns